# TextBlock Run Background Span Whole Line

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textblock

Is it possible to make a run span the entire width of a `TextBlock` so the background looks natural and not just on the text of the run?

Current Result:
[image: The Background only spans the length of the text.]

Expected Result:
[image: The Background spans the entire textbox.]

Another issue with the first image is that there are (unwanted) white lines between certain `Runs` (in this case "test" and "1"). My current code is:

```
Run r = new Run("You: " + SendMessageBox.Text + "\n");
r.Background = Brushes.LightBlue;
ChatHistory.Inlines.Add(r);
```

Comment: Why can't u use a list view?

Comment: Size of the Run depends on the parent control. Grid will give the `TextBlock` all possible space within the Grid, StackPanel will only give enough so that you can read the text. Beware, if the Grid takes only half of the Window then TextBlock will be half of the Window wide. FYI ListView uses a StackPanel for it's `ItemsPanel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to make a run span the entire width of a TextBlock so the background looks natural and not just on the text of the run?

No, you should add another `TextBlock` element for each line:

```
TextBlock t = new TextBlock() { Text = "You: " + SendMessageBox.Text };
t.Background = Brushes.LightBlue;
ChatHistory.Children.Add(t);
```

`ChatHistory` could for example be a `StackPanel`:

Comment: would it be possible to ensure that the little white lines go away? They are barely noticeable with your solution, but are still there :/